# how can i remove any image from an array by clicking ? i try it with .remove (at:0) but it didn't work it removes only in order Using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, image, swiftui, foreach

[image]

How can i remove any image from an array by clicking? I try it with `.remove (at:0)` but it didn't work.  It removes only in order and my goal is to remove any of them.

```
ForEach(mediaItems.items,id: \.id) {    item in
    ZStack{
        HStack {
            if item.mediaType == .photo {
                Image(uiImage:item.photo ?? UIImage())
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 112, height: 90)
                    .cornerRadius(13)
            } else if item.mediaType == .video {
                if let url = item.url {
                    VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
                        .frame(minHeight: 200)
                } else { EmptyView() }
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
        Image("Tracé 2424")
            .offset(x: 40, y: -30)
            .onTapGesture{
                //        mediaItems.items.remove(at:0)
            }
        
        
    }
} //foreach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.enumerated()` to get an index for each `item`.  You'll need to change:

```
ForEach(mediaItems.items, id: \.id) { item in
```

to:

```
ForEach(Array(mediaItems.items.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
```

and then use `index` in `mediaItems.items.remove(at: index)`:

```
ForEach(Array(mediaItems.items.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
    ZStack {
        HStack {
            if item.mediaType == .photo {
                Image(uiImage:item.photo ?? UIImage())
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 112, height: 90)
                    .cornerRadius(13)
            } else if item.mediaType == .video {
                if let url = item.url {
                    VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
                        .frame(minHeight: 200)
                } else { EmptyView() }
            }
                                
        }
                                                                   
        Image("Tracé 2424")
            .offset(x: 40, y: -30)
            .onTapGesture {
                mediaItems.items.remove(at: index)
        }
                                    
    }
} //foreach
```

---

### Alternate method: Filter array based on `id`

Since each item has a unique `id`, you can filter your array and keep items that don't have the same `id` as the current `item`:

Replace:

```
mediaItems.items.remove(at:0)
```

with:

```
mediaItems.items = mediaItems.items.filter { $0.id != item.id }
```

Comment: Thank you but i got an error in the first line "Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'EnumeratedSequence<[PhotoPickerModel]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'"

Comment: How about `ForEach(Array(mediaItems.items.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in`

Answer (score 0):

can u try it

```
mediaItems.item =  mediaItems.item.map { $0.id != item.id }
```

Comment: it didn't work :(